# How do I supress dialogs from an exe that is executed using System.Diagnostic.Process?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, process

I'm using a System.Diagnostic.Process to call another .exe. I'm creating an application which purpose is to run on a remote server. This .exe sometimes crashes and there's a message popup stopping the whole process -> [Application Name] has encountered a problem and is forced to close. I'm trying to find a way to make my c# program ignore this popup and continue executing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is fixing the error with the .exe being called not an option?

Comment: +1 I was thinking the same. Always better to fix the root cause rather than coding around it elsewhere

Comment: Actually I'm not responsible for the code of the .exe program, and I want to avoid any problems it could encounter

Comment: We need more info on the natural of your program and the .exe that you're calling, really.

In an ideal world, you should fix the .exe and make your code handle the errors.

Comment: My exe opens a file and scan the file for certain data, the file names that the exe opens are provided by a database. If the file doesn't exist anymore or the database file path is wrong, the .exe crashed and displays the error. I cannot change the code of the .exe and I need it absolutely to make my whole program to work.

Answer (score 1):

In that case when your process does not work properly you will see a popup thats windows default but if you want to know that process ran successfully or not then this code will work for you

Subscribe to the Process.Exited event and then check Process.ExitCode:

```
 public void StartProcess()
{
 p.StartInfo.FileName = BasePath;
 p.StartInfo.Arguments = args;
 p.Start();
 p.Exited += new EventHandler(Process_Exited);
}

void Process_Exited(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
var p = sender as Process;
if (p.ExitCode != 0)
    MessageBox.Show(string.Format("Process failed: ExitCode = {0}", p.ExitCode));
}
```

Comment: if you are not responsible for the Exe. this was the same problem with me just give them the message that contact system administrator and show the exit code and log it into database that will notify every user.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO the cleanest option to run such a buggy exe is to start it giving to your process debug privileges over it (you probably have to call explicitly `CreateProcess` via P/Invoke with the `DEBUG_PROCESS` flag in the process creation flags) and then have a thread process the debug events provided by [`WaitForDebugEvent`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms681423%28v=VS.85%29.aspx); whenever you get an unhandled, last-chance exception you can notify the main thread, kill the child process (thus avoiding the default Windows exception handler) and restart it if necessary, in all other cases just call [`ContinueDebugEvent`](http://ContinueDebugEvent) to let the program run normally.

Notice that the pointer to the "event structure" provided by `WaitForDebugEvent` could be tricky to work with in C#.

---

***edit***: fortunately it seems that someone made a nice managed wrapper for the native debugging API, see [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jmstall/archive/2006/07/05/managed-wrappers-for-native-debug-api.aspx).